# GridGain - Load data from HBase

Tags: gridgain

I have an application that queries HBase and persist those data to an Oracle database. These data is used for report generation. I would like know whether the same approach is possible when using GridGain in place of Oracle database. Is it possible to get the HBase data and load it to the GridGain memory cache and use for generating reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach of loading data into GridGain cache is the right approach. Once loaded, you will be either able to run [Parallel Computations](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Distributed+Computations) or [Distributed SQL Queries](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/SQL%2C+Scan%2C+And+Full+Text+Queries) directly over GridGain cache.

Comment: So is there any API available in Gridgain that can query the HBase and load data to GridGain In-Memory Database?

Comment: I would use `GridDataLoader` API to load data into GridGain. Take a look at this example: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheDataLoaderExample.java . You can also implement your own HBase `GridCacheStore` which will be responsible for data loading, see generic example here: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/store/CacheStoreLoadDataExample.java